# sort array element in a ascending order in Core java?

Tags: java, sorting

```
class Ascendingarray { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {  //Without using Arrays.sort function 
        int i; int nos[] = {12,9,-4,-1,3,10,34,12,11};       
        System.out.print("Values before sorting: \n"); 

        for(i = 0; i < nos.length; i++) 
            System.out.println( nos[i]+" "); 
        //sort(nos, nos.length); 
        System.out.print("Values after sorting: \n"); 
        for(i = 0; i
```

Comment: I have tried but it's not working.Will you please give explanation?

Comment: Collections.sort **is** part of core Java

Comment: You might want to phrase your actual question?

Comment: put the code into the proper format using{},Not just write as text

Answer (score 2):

You can sort it by your own with a sorting method like bubblesort. Use nested for loops.

```
    for (int j = 0; j<array.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
            if (array[j] < array[k]) {
                int buffer = array[j];
                array[j] = array[k];
                array[k] = buffer; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for sorting

```
for (int j = 0; j<array.length-1; j++) {
        for (int k = j+1; k < array.length; k++){
            if (array[j] < array[k]) {
                int dummy = array[j];
                array[j] = array[k];
                array[k] = dummy; 
            }
        }
    }
```